# Preventing SQL injection when connecting to the database

Tags: php, mysql, validation, mysqli, sql-injection

Is it necessary to validate user input when initially connecting to a mySQL database? Consider the following example in PHP where the initial connection to the database is being made based on user input to a form (for example, through a form that allows the administrator to change the database credentials that are stored in a file on the server):

`$mysqli = new PDO('mssqli:host=' . $_REQUEST['host'] . ';dbname=' . $_REQUEST['db'] . ', $_REQUEST['username'], $_REQUEST['password']);`

Is there a need to validate the $_REQUEST variable, i.e. could an SQL injection take place here? If so, is there a way to parameterize this command?
Thanks for your help.
Regards

Comment: You should have a .ini file with the conn data

Comment: That isn't SQL so there's no risk of an SQL injection attack (which is a particular type of risk). However, there may be other risks with using unvalidated user input like that. (For instance, what if `$_REQUEST['host']` contained a `;`?)

Comment: Consider: An attacker has a the address of a government sql server that has been compromised, and sees your form that allows him to specify all of these values. You would allow your server to become the  attacker proxy, and when the feds come knocking, its going to be to your address.

Comment: Holy tish buckets. What is the purpose of this design? Sure, it *can* be sanitized but what you need is validation to restrict the input to only specific strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a need to validate the $_REQUEST variable

At least it would be a good idea.

> could an SQL injection take place here?

the only sane case for such a code is when a user is a database owner too. So, he scarcely would inject into a database he is already allowed in. Also, there is no SQL to inject, to be strict.

> If so, is there a way to parameterize this command?

No